# On the behaviour of $\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\(n,k)=1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[\alpha]{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, mobius-inversion

For integers $a,b\geq 1$ we denote with $(a,b)$ their greatest common divisor, and the $\alpha$th root with $ \sqrt[\alpha]{x} =x^{1/\alpha}$, where $\alpha\geq 2$. Here with $\mu(n)$ we denote the Möbius function. Then I did calculations following the ideas of [1], for a different example, to get

$$\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\(n,k)=1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[\alpha]{n}}=\frac{1}{\alpha} \left( \sum_{d\mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{\sqrt[\alpha]{d}} \right)\log x+O(1),$$ where $k$ denotes a positive number. But I don't know how do calculations for 
$$\sum_{d\mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{\sqrt[\alpha]{d}}$$ with the purpose to obtain a more eleaborated and concise result.

> **Question** For $\alpha\geq 2$, what's your approach to get the asymptotic behaviour of
>   $$\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\(n,k)=1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[\alpha]{n}},$$
>   as $x$ is large?. **Many thanks.**

My thoughts were about Möbius inversion, but I didn't get nothing useful.

---

[1] Murty, *Problems in Analytic Number Theory*, Second Edition, GTM 206 Springer (2008). I am saying that the ideas of my calculations were from exercises likes to Exercise 1.5.1 or Exercise 1.5.8.

Comment: Using that $\mu(d)/d^{1/ \alpha}$ is multiplicative, you can show that $\sum_{d|k} \mu(d)/d^{1/ \alpha}$ is multiplicative as well. As a consequence, one can prove $$\sum_{d|k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^{1/ \alpha}} = \frac{\mu(k)}{k} \prod_{p|k}p^{-1/ \alpha}$$

Comment: Many thanks for your attention @Crostul

Comment: Come on... How do you show $\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\(n,k)=1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[\alpha]{n}}=\frac{1}{\alpha} \left( \sum_{d\mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{\sqrt[\alpha]{d}} \right)\log x+O(1)$ ? And why do you think there is a simplification of $ \sum_{d\mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{\sqrt[\alpha]{d}}$  ? And why do you write $\sqrt[\alpha]{d}$ instead of $d^{-s}, s = 1/a$ ?

Comment: You are welcome, I did my calculations following the exercises from the cited book. Is it wrong? I would like to learn the approach for $$\sum_{\substack{n\leq x\\(n,k)=1}}\frac{1}{\sqrt[\alpha]{n}},$$ Thanks @user1952009

Comment: That's not your question. The answer is in the link you cited. And why would you/we want to know that ?

Comment: THe answer isn't in the book of Murty, I am asking a different exercise. And my purpose is learn this exercise @user1952009

Comment: What means $\mathcal{O}(1)$ ? Since for $Re(s) > 1$ : $\sum_{n,  (n,k) = 1} n^{-s} = \zeta(s)   \prod_{p | k} (1-p^{-s})$ you have for $Re(s) < 1$ :  $\sum_{n < x, (n,k) = 1} n^{-s} \sim C x^{1-s}$ where $C =  \prod_{p | k} (1-p^{-s})= \sum_{d | k} \mu(d) d^{-s}$ @Crostul

Comment: Can tell me is was an exercise (what?), or if you tell me that it is easily deduced from some theorem of the book that I cited? Thanks @user1952009

Comment: I try with a different example inspired in Exercise 1.5.1 or Exercise 1.5.8, but now I don't see the same exercise or an statement from which I can deduce the result as a specialization. Many thanks for you attention, you are welcome if you want add an answer ,@user1952009

Comment: I forgot a $1/(1-s)$ factor. For $Re(s) < 1$ :  $\sum_{n < x} n^{-s} \sim \int_1^x t^{-s}dx \sim \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}$

Comment: Instead of saying thank you, can you use what I wrote for answering **rigorously** to your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $f$ is a smooth function, one method to obtain the asymptotic behaviour of

$$F_k(x) := \sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ (n,k) = 1}} f(n)$$

is using Abel's sum formula. We know pretty well how many $n \leqslant x$ that are coprime to $k$ we have:

$$N_k(x) = \sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ (n,k) = 1}} 1 = \sum_{n \leqslant x} \chi_0(n) = \frac{\varphi(k)}{k}\cdot x + O_k(1),$$

where $\chi_0$ is the principal character modulo $k$ and $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. The bound on the error term depends on $k$ as indicated, but on nothing else. Thus Abel's formula yields

$$F_k(x) = N_k(x)\cdot f(x) - \int_1^x N_k(t)\cdot f'(t)\,dt\,.$$

With $f(t) = t^{-s}$ and $s \neq 1$, this gives

\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ (n,k) = 1}} \frac{1}{n^s}
&= \frac{N_k(x)}{x^s} + s \int_1^x \frac{N_k(t)}{t^{s+1}}\,dt \\
&= \frac{\varphi(k)}{k}\Biggl(x^{1-s} + s\int_1^x \frac{t}{t^{s+1}}\,dt\Biggr)
+ \frac{O_k(1)}{x^s} + s\int_1^x \frac{O_k(1)}{t^{s+1}}\,dt \\
&= \frac{\varphi(k)}{k}\cdot \Biggl(\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s} - \frac{s}{1-s}\Biggr)
+ \frac{O_k(1)}{x^s} + s\int_1^x \frac{O_k(1)}{t^{s+1}}\,dt\,.
\end{align}

When $\sigma = \operatorname{Re} s$ is non-positive this yields

$$\frac{\varphi(k)}{k}\cdot \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s} + O_k(x^{-\sigma})$$

and when $\sigma > 0$ the integral converges as $x \to \infty$, and writing it as $\int_1^{\infty} - \int_x^{\infty}$ we obtain

$$\sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ (n,k) = 1}} \frac{1}{n^s} = \frac{\varphi(k)}{k}\cdot \frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s} + C + O_k(x^{-\sigma})\,.$$

For $s = 1$ we obtain

\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{ n \leqslant x \\ (n,k) = 1}} \frac{1}{n}
&= \frac{N_k(x)}{x} + \int_1^x \frac{N_k(t)}{t^2}\,dt \\
&= \frac{\varphi(k)}{k}\Biggl(1 + \int_1^x \frac{t}{t^2}\,dt\Biggr) + O_k(x^{-1}) + \int_1^x \frac{O_k(1)}{t^2}\,dt \\
&= \frac{\varphi(k)}{k}\log x + C + O_k(x^{-1})\,.
\end{align}

This method yields good asymptotics with little effort, but the downside is that one gets no useful formula for the constant term $C$. And its applicability is restricted by the requirement that $f$ be differentiable. If $f$ were a non-smooth arithmetical function like the divisor function we couldn't use this at all.

Another method is to inject the Möbius function, using

$$\sum_{d \mid m} \mu(d) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if } m = 1, \\ 0 &\text{if } m > 1.\end{cases}$$

Then we can write

\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ (n,k) = 1}} f(n)
&= \sum_{n \leqslant x} \Biggl(\sum_{d \mid (n,k)} \mu(d)\Biggr)f(n) \\
&= \sum_{d \mid k} \mu(d) \Biggl(\sum_{m \leqslant x/d} f(dm)\Biggr)
\end{align}

changing the order of summation. This is of course only helpful if we can compute

$$\sum_{m \leqslant x/d} f(dm)$$

sufficiently accurately. If $f$ is a completely multiplicative function, like in the cases we're looking at here, this is usually easier than for general $f$, since we can pull $f(d)$ out of the sum. For $f(n) = 1/n$ we have

$$\sum_{n \leqslant y} \frac{1}{n} = \log y + \gamma + O(y^{-1})$$

and thus

\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ (n,k) = 1}} \frac{1}{n}
&= \sum_{d \mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}\sum_{m \leqslant x/d} \frac{1}{m} \\
&= \sum_{d \mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}\bigl(\log x + \gamma - \log d + O(d/x)\bigr) \\
&= \Biggl(\sum_{d \mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}\Biggr)\log x + \gamma \sum_{d \mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} - \sum_{d \mid k} \frac{\mu(d)\log d}{d} + O_k(x^{-1})\,.
\end{align}

Now we note that for a multiplicative (it need not be completely multiplicative) function $g$ we have

$$\sum_{d \mid k} \mu(d)\cdot g(d) = \prod_{p \mid k}\bigl(1 - g(p)\bigr),$$

so

$$\sum_{d \mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} = \prod_{p \mid k} \biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p}\biggr) = \frac{\varphi(k)}{k},$$

as we also know from the first part. We thus have gained an explicit formula for the constant term (which is still infeasible to compute for large $k$ in general, since we need the factorisation of $k$).

For $f(n) = 1/n^s$ with $s\neq 1$ we find

$$\sum_{n \leqslant y} \frac{1}{n^s} = \frac{y^{1-s}}{1-s} + \zeta(s) + O(y^{-\sigma})$$

(where $\sigma = \operatorname{Re} s$) by Abel's sum formula, Euler's sum formula or the Euler-Maclaurin formula. (For $\sigma \leqslant 0$, the appearance of the constant term $\zeta(s)$ is spurious, this should be absorbed in the error term then, or one should use the Euler-Maclaurin formula to get more terms in the asymptotic expansion.) Plugging that in, we obtain

\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ (n,k) = 1}} \frac{1}{n^s}
&= \sum_{d \mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^s} \sum_{m \leqslant x/d} \frac{1}{m^s} \\
&= \sum_{d \mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^s} \biggl(\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}d^{s-1} + \zeta(s) + O(d^{\sigma}x^{-\sigma})\biggr) \\
&= \Biggl(\sum_{d\mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}\Biggr)\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s} + \zeta(s)\sum_{d \mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^s} + O_k(x^{-\sigma})\,.
\end{align}

Again we find an expression for the constant term (which however is only relevant for $\sigma > 0$, unless we take more terms of the asymptotic expansion into account), namely

$$\zeta(s) \sum_{d \mid k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^s} = \zeta(s)\prod_{p \mid k}\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{p^s}\biggr) = L(s,\chi_0)\,.$$

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation.